# PostgreSQL - are ENABLE/DISABLE trigger rolled back?

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-11

I have a PL/pgSQL function whose body contains some regular/normal DML statements... like UPDATE, DELETE, etc.

But also there are in this function's body statements like:

`ALTER TABLE sc.TBL DISABLE TRIGGER TR_TBL_Delete;  --- 1`

and also

`ALTER TABLE sc.TBL ENABLE TRIGGER TR_TBL_Delete;  --- 2`

Now... I know that if an error occurs in the body of the func, all changes to the DB made by UPDATE, DELETE, etc. statements will be rolled back. And that will happen no matter if have an EXCEPTION (i.e. catch exception) block as part of the main func block or not.

**Note that at entering the function all triggers are in ENABLED state.** 
So I want to be 100% sure that at exiting the function they will also be in ENABLED state.

So... I have some worries about this... I wonder if it's possible some trigger to remain in DISABLED state because a statement of the form `--- 2` was not reached (due to the error which occurred).

In a way I wonder if `ENABLE TRIGGER/DISABLE TRIGGER` statements also participate in that transaction in which the func body is executed.

I need an authoritative answer with some references to official docs, if possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried this myself with a few simple tests.

These ENABLE/DISABLE trigger statements do participate in the transaction.
This means it's working as I wanted/expected it to work.

The tests I did show that if the function *disables a trigger A, and then encounters an error before reaching the respective enable trigger A statement*, these changes made to the trigger are rolled back. Thus... after the function returns the trigger is still in enabled state.

```
BEGIN
    ALTER TABLE TBL DISABLE TRIGGER A;

    -- do some work (success) 

    -- more work here... but an error is raised

    ALTER TABLE TBL ENABLE TRIGGER A; -- (not executed)

    -- some other statements here (not executed) 

END;
```